# Is there an json filter option available in mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb, arraylist, aggregate

In below json file i want to exactly filter the decimal value in child array of text.while excute the sample code the output shown the all the json value instead of filtered value.

sample json file:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("01"),
    "project_id" : "100",
    "snapshot" : "Symbol",
    "obs" : {    
        "land" : {
            "b2" : {
                "points" : [ 
                    "p1", 
                    "p2"
                ]
            }
        "points" : {
            "p1" : {
                "position" : [ 
                    123.00000000, 
                    123.00000000
                ]
            },
            "p2" : {
                "position" : [ 
                    1235.896523, 

                ]
            }
        "text" : {
            "t2" : {
                "box" : [ 
                    [ 
                        123.0, 
                        3361.0
                    ], 
                    [ 
                        117, 
                        60
                    ], 
                    0.0
                ],               
                "value" : "813"
            },
            "t3" : {
                "box" : [ 
                    [ 
                        1260.76745605469, 
                        726.63720703125
                    ], 
                    [ 
                        51.4486427307129, 
                        88.5970306396484
                    ], 
                    -36.2538375854492
                ],                
                "value" : "27.06"
            }
}
```

sample code:

```
db.getCollection('obs').aggregate([{$match: {project_id: "100",snapshot : "Symbol"}},
    {$addFields:{
          "obs.text":{
               $arrayToObject:{
                    $filter:{
                        input:{$objectToArray:"$obs.text"},
                        cond:{
                              $regexMatch:{
                                   input:"$$this.k",
                                   regex:/t/
                              }
                        }             
                    }
               }
          }
    }}
])

Excepted output:
 "_id" : ObjectId("01"),
        "project_id" : "100",
        "snapshot" : "Symbol",
        "obs" : { 
     "text" : {
    "t3" : {               
                    "value" : "27.06"
                }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think you'll need to split that `$addFields` stage so you can modify the value while it is still in an array.

Comment: @Maria Jovanna : You're doing regex on `t` so it would return `t2` & `t3`, Edit this question with required o/p it might be easy that way..